# How To Run Web Aplication in Android Mobile Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, deployment

I created a script to clone several files at once from my Drive to the user's Drive.
After deploying the Apps Script that I created, I successfully ran the Web Application with the Chrome Browser on my computer. For the convenience of users, most of whom are students in my country, who not all can access via computer devices, I tried running the Web Application via Chrome Browser on an Android Mobile device.
Unfortunately it doesn't work yet.
Is there another method so that the Web Application can be done via the Chrome Browser running on a Mobile device?

This is the [Web Aplication](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxfYKbndR0ZCsDIj9qyajM4DRH_2iWTkmlZKVFj9sz6CrHWyI8ir0jSgWD4HvHwbipNDA/exec).

I'm not sure if my question meets the guidelines in this community. If it doesn't fit, I apologize.

Comment: Can you share the Android version of your device and if you're getting any error messages when trying your web app? Also, try to [`Browse in private`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) to check if it'll work. I tried it on both `Android 14` and `iOS 17.2.1` devices, and it worked, so there's a chance that what you've experienced earlier could have been a caching issue.

Comment: Thanks @Saddles , after read your suggestion, I try to run my web app on other Device and   worked.  My Previous Device was  Android 10  OS. 
Regarding the possibility of  'catching issue'  on my previous device, do you have any suggestions for solving it?

Comment: That's good to know! As for your other device, you can [`Clear cache & cookies`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid), and that should do the trick.

Comment: Let me go ahead and rephrase my comments to be an answer to this question since you mentioned that the `suggestion worked`. That way, other community members who stumble upon this post may know this information. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployed web app is already working, except for one of your devices, which got resolved after [`Clear cache & cookies`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050) of its Google Chrome application. [`Browse in private`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) helped since it doesn't save browsing history as well as cookies and site data.